# Flutter: Pod error every time I add a plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I'm going crazy with pod in Android Studio. Every time I add a new plugin in flutter I got some errors and I can't build the app..No problem of course with Android version...

When I add a plugin I run:

pod update in iOS folder

What is the correct procedure? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods is one of iOS dependency manager and has nothing to do with Android or AndroidStudio, where usaully Gradle takes the handling of dependencies.
Usually after adding a new package in *pubspec.yaml* file you either can run `pub get` or just launch the app - this works if you launch yor app from AndroidStudio or IntelliJ where you have Flutter plugin installed.

I assume you have problems mostly with iOS. For this you need to "cd" to your project's iOS directory and run `pod install` - this you need to do if you plan to launch your app from Xcode and not from AndroidStudio or IntelliJ just after you added a new package in *pubspec.yaml* file